# Get bugs from bugzilla using python

Tags: python, bugzilla

I am trying to get bugs to a db from bugzilla rest API. My code is given below.

```
import requests
import json

URL = "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/"

API_KEY = "key"

headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
params = {
              "username": "email",
              "password": "password",
              "apikey": API_KEY,
          }

# r = requests.get(URL + 'login/', headers = headers, params = params)
# print(r)

resp = requests.post(URL + "bug/" , headers = headers, params = params)


if resp.status_code != 200:
    print('error: ' + str(resp.status_code))
else:
    print('Success')
    print(resp)
```

When I try this I get Response 404.

Someone please direct me to the correct path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After poking aroung https://resttesttest.com/ I found the answer. Bugzilla API can be authenticate just by API-KEY. So I removed username and password from params dict. It seems I have an error in concatenating the URL too. I just used "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug/35" to get the bug report on bug_id 35. Then json.load(resp.text) gave the json object of the bug report. Final code looks like this.

```
import requests
import json

URL = "https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug/35"

API_KEY = "key"

headers = {"Content-type": "application/json"}
params = {
              "api_key": API_KEY,
          }

resp = requests.get(URL , headers = headers, params = params)


if resp.status_code != 200:
    print('error: ' + str(resp.status_code))
else:
    print('Success')
    print(json.loads(resp.text))
```

Comment: apikey should be changed to *api_key* or *Bugzilla_api_key*.