# How to resolve Bad Requests in python (pycharm)?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am working on the requests library in python where I am requesting the API of Bugzilla. The API works fine in postman but the script which I have written from the below link is not working and sending the response back as Bad Request 400. I have added the code below.

[Get bugs from bugzilla using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551580/get-bugs-from-bugzilla-using-python)

```
import requests
import json

URL = 'https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug/35'

API_KEY = "api_key"

headers = {
    "content-type": "application/json"
}

params = {
    "api_key": API_KEY,
}

try:
    response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers, params=params)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print(f'error : {response.status_code}')
        print(response.reason)
    else:
        print('Success')
        print(json.load(response.text))
except response:
    print(response)
```

Comment: There is no general solution to solve this. The URL you are requesting defines what is required. I suggest `print(response.body)` to see if there's additional information to tell you what you need to do.

Comment: response.body doesn't exists.

Comment: I have checked it through print(response.content) which gets the following response {"error":true,"documentation":"https://bmo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/","message":"The API key you specified is invalid. Please check that you typed it correctly.","code":306}'

Comment: My guess is `API_KEY = "api_key"` is not a valid API key. Are you using an actual key or is this just a placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are sending wrong api key

try to get your api key via:

```
r = requests.get('https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/login?login=username&password=password')
r.text
```

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:REST_API

Comment: Thanks all for your kind feedback. I have done some alterations in the code and it works for me. I am attaching the updated version of the code.

Comment: import requests
import json

URL = 'https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug/35'

response = requests.get(URL)

if response.status_code != 200:
    print(f'error : {response.status_code}')
    print(response.content)
else:
    print('Success')
    print(json.loads(response.text))

Comment: As doc said, this specific url that you are calling is a public url and doesn't need auth. But consider that you need api key for private urls

Comment: @Samikhan You should post your solution in its own answer below rather than in a comment.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for your correction. I confess my bad and next time I will surely do it.

Comment: @Samikhan Feel free to do it this time so that your solution can help future visitors to this page.